# what is the better way to substring large text?

Tags: java, string, file, substring, file-read

Suppose my file is 2GB, I want some specific data from one. index  to another index(considering specific data 300MB between two index), what is the better way to do that?? I tried substring but throwing out of memory exception.  Please suggest better way to do same.

Comment: `RandomAccessFile`? `FileChannel`?

Answer (score 3):

In general, assuming that 2GB file is on disk, and you want to read some part from it into memory, you absolutely don't have to read the whole 2GB into memory first.

The most straightforward solution is using [Random Access File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

The point is that it provides an abstraction of a pointer that can be moved back and forth over a big file and once you're set you can read bytes from the place the pointer points on.

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r");
file.seek(position);
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
file.read(bytes);
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file by character and writing them to the output file can solve the issue. Since it won't load the whole file at once.

So, the process will be - read the input file by character, continue to the desired substring start index, then start writing to an output file until the end of the substring.

If you are getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, you can try increasing the heap size if you really need to read the file at once and you are sure that String size won't go past max String size limit.

The following snippet shows the idea above -

```
import java.io.*;

public class LargeFileSubstr {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/me/Downloads/big.txt"));

        try (PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/me/Downloads/big_substr.txt"))) {
            int startIndex = 100;
            int endIndex = 200;
            int pointer = 0;
            int ch;

            while ((ch = r.read()) != -1) {

                if (pointer > endIndex) {
                    break;
                }

                if (pointer >= startIndex) {
                    wr.print((char) ch);
                }

                pointer++;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried this to take a 200MB substring out of 2GB file, works pretty reasonably fast.

Comment: Note that strings and arrays in general have a 2.4 gigabyte limit in Java (`Integer.MAX_VAULE` length specifically)

Comment: Yup, INTEGER.MAX_VALUE is 2.4 but we can't do this on server ri8? Already there are lots of process going on.

Comment: It's highly recommended not to load the file into a string at once. Because, even after you are done working with the string, it will be living in JVM pool until next GC